# calculating average length of words in a local text file

Tags: c++

I need to find the 
- average length of all the words
- the shortest and longest word length; and 
- how many words are 
in a separate text file, using c++. There are 79 words in the file and it is called "test.txt."

what i have so far is

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
#include <cstdio> 


using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    FILE* fp; 
    char buffer[100]; 

    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r"); 
    while (!feof(fp)) // to read file 
    { 
        // fucntion used to read the contents of file 
        fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 100, fp); 
        cout << buffer; 
    } 


    return 0; 
}
```

All this does is print out the words that are in the file.

I am using an online compiler until i can get to my desktop with visual studio 2017 later today

Comment: This seems to have some rather straight forward next steps... Can you print out the length of each line? Can you add these lengths to an array? Can you take the average of an array of numbers?  Please try these things and let us know if anything specific trips you up

Comment: Hi, you're not showing any code that determines "what is a word" and how long those words are, much less calculating an average.   Also none of your code uses C++ techniques; it's all plain old C.

Comment: @Hoog I just cant get it to gather the string from a separate text file. The words are line by line in the file. e.g We (end line) are (end line) the (end line) best (end line)

Comment: `fread()` will read the specified number of characters, which is unrelated to individual words (or lines for that matter) in the file.   You need to first check if `fread()` succeeds before doing anything with `buffer`  (e.g. printing as you are gives undefined behaviour if `fread()` fails).     Then examine the contents of `buffer` to find words (or the whitespace between them).    `fread()` also assumes a binary file, and your code does not open the file in binary mode.    There are better options to read the file than `fread()` if you want to read individual lines or words.

Comment: @ToniOluwole The approach proposed in my answer, would work with a word per line input as well. New line characters (_end line_ in your terminology) would be ignored by the text extraction `operator>>()`, because they count as _whitespace_.

Comment: No class objects?  not even stream?  sorry, wrong tag.

Answer (score 2):

Well, with c++ instead of `FILE*` rather use a `std::ifstream`, a `std::string word;` variable and formatted text extraction `operator>>()` to read single words from the file in a loop:

```
std::ifstream infile("test.txt");
std:string word;
while(infile >> word) {
}
```

Count every word read from the file in a variable `int wordCount;`

```
int wordCount = 0;
while(infile >> word) {
    ++wordCount;
}
```

Sum up the character lengths of the read words in another variable `int totalWordsCharacters;` (you can use the `std::string::length()` function to determine the number of characters used in a word).

```
int totalWordsCharacters = 0;
while(infile >> word) {
    totalWordsCharacters += word.length();
}
```

After you completed reading that file, you can easily compute the average length of words by dividing

```
int avgCharacterPerWord = totalWordsCharacters / wordCount;
```

[**Here's a complete working example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f57285e3d4fce293), the only difference is the `'\n'` in your input file format was replaced by a simple blank character (`' '`).

Comment: disregard the last comment, removed precompiled headers. It should work, but visual studio on my computersays there's an integer division by zero in line 18 with wordCount

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the average between ALL the words, you have to add all lengths together and divide it by the number of words in your file (You said 79 words)

But if you want to get the average between only the shortest word and the longest one you will have to first: Get those words.

You can do that by simply use two counters as you go through all words. The first counter will be set to the length of the current word if it has a smaller length as the first counter. The second counter will be set to the length of the current word if it has a grater length as the second counter.

Then you will add those two counters together and divide them by 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are writing C Code. This makes the problem harder.

In C++ reading a list of words from a file is simple using the `>>` operator.

```
std::ifstream  file("FileName");
std::string    word;
while(file >> word)
{
    // I have read another word from the file.
    // Do your calculations here.
}
// print out your results here after the loop.
```

Note the `>>` operator treats end of line just like a space and simply ignores it (It acts like a word separator).

Comment: Thank you, will integrate this